# how to resolve React error Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to learn React. I am trying to display the string Hello World but get the following error in my browser:

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
> SyntaxError: C:\react\react-app\src\index.js: Missing semicolon. (1:6)

And I get these errors in my Editor:
1)'import ... =' can only be used in TypeScript files.
2)'=' expected.
3)';' expected.

My code is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom form "react-dom";

const element = <h1>Hello World</h1>;
ReactDom.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: There's a typo in import of react-dom. It should be `from` instead of `form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See neeraj tk's comment = correct answer

I typed from instead of form. When I fixed this the code worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**index.tsx**

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <react-app />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: thank you, I tried your code and then the first two errors went away but I still get the following error:  ',' expected. ts (1005) [Ln5,Col5]

The code is used was:
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <react-app />
    </React.StrictMode>
    document.getElementById('root')
  );

Comment: if use ts , you can try i edited